# Fragment ID didnt change after frament switching

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I ran into a problem that after changing a fragment, the ID of the current fragment remains the same, but if I navigate between fragments via NavigationDrawer everything works fine  My application has a NavigationDrawer, and fragments id changing. I launch the fragment change from the Dashboard of the fragment by clicking on the CardView.

I get the fragment id using the code in MainActivity:

```
NavDestination current = NavHostFragment.findNavController(Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportFragmentManager().getPrimaryNavigationFragment()).getFragmentManager()).getFragments().get(0)).getCurrentDestination();
int tagid = current.getId();
```

I perform a fragment change using the following code:

```
 switchFragment(new LastOperFragment());
```

Method:

```
public void switchFragment(Fragment fragment)
    {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are mixing Jetpack Navigation API with the Fragment API. Try to navigate to the new fragment by the [Navigation API](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#id). Somethink like `Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.viewTransactionsAction);` You will see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);
navController.navigate(R.id.your_nav_fragment);